# Changing the logo in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm loving the rails_admin plugin from https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin but I cant for the life of me get my custom logo to replace the installed one.

Anyone have any insight as to how to achieve this? I've tried overriding the css and rails_admin directory/fil structure but it doesnt pick my changes up.

Anyone got any insight as to how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around and asking on the rails_admin google group it appears that this functionality is not supported at the moment.

Comment: So you suggest it's not possible to change image? Is it's content hard-coded into gem that it cannot be replaced?

Comment: Also - why do you answer your own question if it's not answer you expect? You can edit your question if you want

Comment: Because thats the answer to the question, expected or not. This functionality is not supported. Do you have anything to add to this conversation?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just opened this question from recommended on first page of SO and haven't checked it was asked and answered some time ago.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to do this now, there is a supported method - just override the title partial by creating a file at `app/views/rails_admin/main/_title.html.erb` (or .haml or whatever).

Mine for instance contains:

```
%h1.title
  = link_to rails_admin_dashboard_path do
    = image_tag "design/admin_logo.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you just change the logo to put your logo in this place in your application :

```
public/images/rails_admin/logo.png
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've already tried this and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is right and if rails_admin author wants you too, but a dirty method is to go into your rails_admin gem and rename (or delete) assets folders so Rails don't find the Rack assets so it fallbacks on Rails ones that you've copied through :

```
rake admin:copy_assets
```

Then you just have to modify the ones in your app public directory.

I know it's kind of a hack and you'll have to do it again if you update the gem.
And again, I don't know if it's a good advise since I don't know Rails Admin author's policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the **/app/views/layouts/rails_admin** folder, located in the gem installation folder (bundle show rails_admin), into your project's **app/views/layouts** folder. Then you can modify the _header.html.erb partial, on the line:

```
span class="image_replacement"><%= @plugin_name %>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be:

```
before_filter :if => Proc.new{ |c| c.request.path =~ /admin/ } do 
  @head_stylesheet_paths = ['admin_screen.css'] 
end
```

Then you override the image_replacement class with a bang important.

```
.image_replacement{
  background-image:url(...) !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
public/images/rails_admin/logo.png
```

Should work as long as you also did this:

```
rake admin:copy_assets
```

As part of your install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it extremely easily with pure scss. Sometimes the simplest thing that could work will work :)

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-image: image_url('logo.png');
  background-size: auto $navbar-height; // put your own sizes here
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.brand {
  display: none !important; //get rid of the text
}
```

Comment: Although with the brand hidden the link back to dashboard root is broken, but the one on the right still works. My logo is more important :)